Code injection not working outside of <head> if loaded in <head>
All of my injected scripts are loaded in the head tag.
This works
<head>
        (function() {
            const target = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var myScript = document.createElement('script');

    myScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/plain');myScript.setAttribute('data-cookiecategory', 'analytics');
        myScript.innerHTML = 'window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[];function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}gtag("js",new Date());gtag("config","id");';if(target == null){return};
            target.prepend(myScript);
        })();
</head>

however this doesn't work (the element in not created)
<head>
(function() {
            const target = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            var myScript = document.createElement('script');

    myScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/plain');myScript.setAttribute('data-cookiecategory', 'analytics');
        myScript.innerHTML = 'window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[];function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}gtag("js",new Date());gtag("config","id");';if(target == null){return};
            target.prepend(myScript);
        })();</script>;
</head>

It certainly had to do with how the script is loaded.
Considering I cannot load the injection scripts outside the head (the js injection file comes from a remote server, loaded dynamically on the website) is there a way around this?

The way you show your code shouldn't work in either case. You're missing the correct <script> tags. (Did you mean for <head> to be <script> instead?)

When your second script runs, <body> doesn't exist yet, so the first line fails (returns undefined) - debug your variables to see what's happening.   (assuming <script> tags as per above comment)

You might like to also reformat your script so it's easier to discover - that if(target == null){return}; is hidden away on the far right yet applies to the target.prepend line

Why do you think you need to prepend the script to the body instead of the head? It will run no matter where you attach it.

yeah it was just an example i Wrote here, script if course include. I fixed the issue using defer attribute
